# Overriding NFS calls to linux kernel

Tags: linux, nfs

I need to overide NFS calls such as vfs_unlink but have had no success so far.
I have managed to successfully intercept samba calls to unlink().

I used

```
export LD_PRELOAD="/home/space/wrapper-debug.so"
```

and all intercepting code is there for samba and NFS.

For samba I have

```
int unlink(const char * path) { ... }
```

which works and for NFS I have

```
int vfs_unlink(struct inode *dir, struct dentry *dentry, struct inode **delegated_inode)    
{...}
```

but this function doesn't seem to be called.

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That appears to be an internal kernel function. You can't override it from user space.

Comment: In general, from user space, a file is a file, and finding out what type of file system it's actually on, or whether it's even a real file or something like a `/proc` pseudo-file, is difficult. Even if you can sort that out in user land, you won't want to be doing it on every file operation call...

Comment: But that's what I'm doing for samba unlink calls and I managed to override these calls and do my own thing.  There must be a way of doing this in NFS but have not been able to find out what call to override if it's possible at all.

Comment: If you have Samba running in a "file system in user space" configuration (i.e. not using the kernel's `smbfs`/`cifs` file system drivers), then you can override file system calls in the user space program that emulates them. But for `smbfs`/`cifs`/`nfs`/`ext*`/`xfs` and a whole bunch more, the calls are implemented in the kernel where user space programs/libraries can't touch them. You would have to write a kernel module or modify the existing kernel drivers to achieve that...